# Laravel Auth::attempt($credentials) results in Undefined array key "password"

Tags: laravel

I am working with Laravel, and am trying to use Auth to login a user, with a different model than User and a different table name. I modified my config\auth.php file and changed the model as well as the table name.

However, when logging in, I get this strange error, stating: Undefined array key "password".

Here is my controller code:

```
function NewUser_homePost(Request $request) 
{
    // Validate the request data

    $credentials = $request->only('Username', 'Password');

    // Attempt to login
    // Error appears here: stating Undefined array key "password"
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect(route('New_Home'))->with("success", "Logged in successfully");
    }

    // Authentication failed...
    return redirect(route('Home'))->with("error", "Login details are not valid");
}
```

Is there some place where keys are stored in Auth?

Comment: `$credentials = $request->only('Username', 'Password');` should probably be `$credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');`. PHP Array Keys are case-sensitive, so by using `'Password'`, `$credentials['password']` is indeed `undefined`.

Comment: for `attempt` the "password" field **must** be named `'password'` ... this does not directly relate to the name of the field on the table

Answer (score 0):

you need to check what is your input type for the password field

pass
    
 
[check form password input type][1]